Asian film where gangster character has "gills"
A few years ago, I saw a clip from a (possibly Japanese?) movie where a gangster-ish character with blond hair takes a draw from a cigarette, then blows the smoke out through slits in the side of his face. It looked like he had shark gills, but I believe the slits were from a Glasgow smile that had been "repaired" by piercing together the normal corners of his mouth.
It was a cool visual effect that really stuck with me and I have absolutely no idea where it's from and no idea where I even saw the clip. Any help identifying this film would be appreciated.

Takashi Miike's Ichi the Killer from 2001, based on a manga called Koroshiya 1.

Yakuza boss Anjo disappears with three hundred million yen. His loyal gang members, lead by the masochist Kakihara, start a search, but their aggressive and gory methods worry the other yakuza gangs. Kakiharas most frightening counterpart is the mysterious Ichi, a psychopathic killer with a dark childhood secret, who is controlled by a retired cop.


